# How to remove the "301 Moved Permanently" text that shows up on the client side?

Tags: php, 301-redirect

How do you remove the following text:

> 301 Moved Permanently. The document has been permanently moved.

that shows up on our web site's home page?

I have used a web crawler to identify what links were being redirected and "unlinked" them. I've also commented out the `RewriteCond` & `RewriteRule` in the `.htaccess` file that could have been causing the redirect message (those using flag [R=301,L]). I've reloaded the website but the message still appears. (Also I'd cleared browser cache to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't.)

The website was designed using Joomla 1.5.23. I have tried to find the php file that generates the home page but haven't found it yet.

Any help or suggestions on how to remove this message from the home page would be most appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As i understand  you see this just before  redirection

You see  this becuse  php  creates  header ( with  header() function)  after some other output.

In php if you want  to redirect (without info about 301)  you need to call header() function before anty other output (echo or something)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php